# Trouble requiring sequelize model with express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to configure sequelize in a modular way but I'm having trouble when requiring my models.

I have the following code for initialisation:

```
// sequelize.js
module.exports = {
  init() {
    if (!db) {
      db = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
        host,
        dialect
      })
      db
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
          logging.info('Connection has been established successfully.')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          logging.error(`Unable to connect to the database: ${err}`)
        })
      return Promise.resolve(db)
    }
    return Promise.resolve(db)
  },
  define(...args) {
    if (db) {
      return db.define(args)
    }
    throw new Error('init the db first before defining models')
  }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
'use strict'
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import sequelize from '../sequelize'

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  email: Sequelize.STRING
})

export default User
```

In my express app I do this:

```
import { user } from './routes'

sequelize.init()
  .then(() => {
    app.use('/v2', user)
    ...
  })
```

And in the user route I have this:

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()
import User from '../models/user'

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.json([])
})
```

However, when I start my app, the router middleware is the first one to be initiated, and it's unable to instantiate a database connection since sequelize,init() is called after `app.use` is done applying middleware.
Obviously I have an ordering error with how I require my modules. I wanted to see if there is a way around this, and if there is a more logical way of initiating my sequelize db connection as the first step.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by `require`ing the route later on like this:

`app.use('/v2', require('./routes/people'))`

Worked perfectly :)